# How can I configure ECS autoscaling to track both CPU and RAM utilisation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I'm working on adding autoscaling to an ECS service. The service is currently configured to use 3 tasks, but there's no scaling policy in place.
The service deals with a number of different workloads - some of the workloads are CPU bound (i.e. metrics calculations), and other workloads are memory-bound (i.e. retrieving large amounts of data). Depending on the time of day, the workload on the server changes, so we would like to be able to scale based on **both** RAM and CPU utilisation - in order to scale for both types of workloads.

I've worked with Kubernetes in the past, and [I know that having two **separate** HPAs (Horizontal Pod Autoscalers) for the same service can cause issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73555411/19307830) (e.g. the service gets scaled up because of the HPA that tracks memory, but then the HPA that tracks CPU scales the service back down). However, I'm not sure about whether ECS has the same issue with conflicting scaling policies.

I've looked at [the AWS docs relating to ECS autoscaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/capacity-autoscaling.html#capacity-autoscaling-app), however, the documentation seems to talk about identifying a **single** metric to track utilisation - for instance:

> To scale effectively, it's critical to identify **a metric** that indicates utilization or saturation

The above implies using a singular metric, and:

> While load testing, examine each of the utilization metrics. The metrics that increase along with the load are the top candidates to serve as your best utilization metrics. [...] At the same time, also **examine the utilization metrics to see which one flattens out at a high level first**. [...] Therefore, **choose the metric that represents the resource that depletes first**. [...] Assume that **the key metric** increases, or decreases, at half the rate as before. If this is the case, then **the metric** is proportional to capacity. This is a good utilization metric for auto scaling.

The above snippet guides you from identifying a set of metrics tied to load, to selecting **a single** metric that's most proportional to load.

As mentioned above, the load on our service changes throughout the day, so we would ideally like to scale based on **both** RAM and CPU utilisation, but the AWS documentation pushes you towards selecting a single metric. Is there a way for us to tie scaling to both metrics, or will tracking multiple metrics lead to conflicting scaling instructions?

Comment: "However, I'm not sure about whether ECS has the same issue with conflicting scaling policies." Yes, it has the same issue with conflicting scaling policies. You could try creating a Composite Alarm that tracks all the metrics you care about, and then configure a single autoscaling policy to use that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using multiple target tracking policies according to AWS

> It will scale out the Auto Scaling group if any of the target tracking policies are ready for scale out, but will scale in only if all of the target tracking policies (with the scale-in portion enabled) are ready to scale in.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35391967)